# High-trust SharePoint Add-ins Redirection (redirect_uri=http)

Tags: redirect

When SharePoint (2013) trying to reach APP on the PHA server it goes to AppRedirect.aspx and shows a request like:

*https://<SITE_URL>/_layouts/15/AppRedirect.aspx?client_id=<CLIENT_ID>&redirect_uri=**http://**<PHA_URL>//DocumentSet/Create?{StandardTokens}&SPHasRedirectedToSharePoint=1*

But we've got a security warning cause HTTP in this request (redirect_uri=http://).
How to change it and where?

What I have done:

- checked app config via Get-SPAppInstance and it shows 'https://' under 'LaunchUrl'
- checked AppManifest.xml and it's 'https://' under  tag
- updated the lates version of app
- on AppRegNew.aspx page when app was registered inside 'Redirect URI' you can put only 'https://'...

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I've added this rule on all WFE servers:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="rewrite" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^_layouts/15/AppRedirect.aspx$" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/_layouts/15/AppRedirect.aspx?{C:1}redirect_uri=https{C:2}" appendQueryString="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)redirect_uri=http(.*)" />
                </conditions>
            </rule>
        </rules>
</rewrite>
```